# Regex for matching in strings

Tags: c#, regex, winforms

What is a regex to match the word `call` or `CALL` in the following string in C#?

```
NIFTY-CALL-1200-Aug11
NIFTY CALL 1200 Aug11
NIFTYCALL-CALL-1200-Aug11 //In this case second call word must be matched not NIFTYCALL.
NIFTYCALL CALL 1200 Aug11 //In this case second call word must be matched not NIFTYCALL.
CALLNIFTY CALL 1200 Aug11 //In this case second call word must be matched not CALLNIFTY.
CALLNIFTY CALL 1200 Aug11 //In this case second call word must be matched not CALLNIFTY.
CALLNIFTY Aug11 1200CALL //In this case last call word must be matched not CALLNIFTY.
CALLNIFTY 1200 Aug11CALL //In this case last call word must be matched not CALLNIFTY.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about

```
Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"(?:\b|[0-9])(CALL)\b", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

- the `(?:<b|[0-9])` part checks for a word boundary or a number preceding CALL
- (`CALL`) finds the string and puts it in a matching group
- the `\b` part again checks for a word boundary.

Comment: ,It works great.Thank you.But I don't understand the first part properly for word boundry (?:<b|[0-9]).

Comment: @Harikrishna - the `\b` is a word boundary, the `|` is equivalent to an `or` statement, the `[0-9]` is a digit (the same as \d as Pengyu used). All this is wrapped into a none capturing group `(?:....)`.

Answer (score 1):

It would be

```
Regex re = new Regex(@"(\d|\b)(CALL|call)(\d|\b)");
```

Answer (score 0):

Could also use

```
Regex re = new Regex(@"(\d|\b)(CALL)(\d|\b)",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

instead of using CALL|call. That way, you'd also match "cAll" or "CALl". (If needed of course).